# Pcolormesh secondary axis ticks missing when set as 'in'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an issue when setting the tick direction to `direction='in'` when using the `secondary_xaxis` function. They appear only when set to `out`

Here is a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def invert(x):
    return (x+1)**-1


dx, dy = 0.15, 0.05

# generate 2 2d grids for the x & y bounds
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-3, 3 + dy, dy),
                slice(-3, 3 + dx, dx)]
z = (1 - x / 2. + x ** 5 + y ** 3) * np.exp(-x ** 2 - y ** 2)

z = z[:-1, :-1]
z_min, z_max = -np.abs(z).max(), np.abs(z).max()


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)

ax.set_xlabel(r'normal')
ax.tick_params(direction='in')

secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(invert, invert))
secax.set_xlabel(r'invert')

secax.tick_params(direction='in')
```

Here is the output:

[image]

But setting `secax.tick_params(direction='out')` gives the correct output:

[image]

Anyone has an idea how to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm... changing the `zorder` allows them to appear, but then they no longer appear on the primary x-axis.

Comment: Changing the `zorder` works fine

Comment: Yeah... it was working intermittently for me so I deleted the answer I had originally posted.... undeleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `zorder` seems to fix this:

```
secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(invert, invert), zorder=3)
```

[image]